# Actionlink with text & icon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this link in clean HTML. I want to make it into a MVC ActionLink. But how is that possible. I cant understund, seems there is no easy way. OR?

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

You have several options for doing this.

Option 1:

```
<li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
```

Option 2:

Write your own extension method for HtmlHelper, that takes in a String/MvcHtmlString and put it into the link tag, without html encoding it.

```
public static MvcHtmlString SpecialActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, String action, String controller, String innerHtml) {
    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
    tag.MergeAttribute("href", new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext).Action(action, controller));
    tag.InnerHtml = innerHtml;
    return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

(Haven't tested it, but should give you an idea on how to do it.)

Answer (score 6):

```
<li class="active">


    @Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", //Title
                    "Index",      // Action
                    "Home",       // Controller
                    new { @class = "home-icon"}  // htmlAttributes 
                    )

</li>


.home-icon{   /*Some CSS to set the background image (not tested) */
   padding:16px;
   background:transparent url('path-to-image.png') .... ;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. I used this for MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3: `<li>@Html.ActionLink(" Logout", "Login", "Account", null, new {@class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"})</li>`

Answer (score 1):

You Can't use ActionLink. only way is @url.action

```
<a href="@Url.Action("View","Article",new {area="",id=id})"><span>This is a test</span></a>
```

Comment: If you want insert Image or html element in your hyperLink,this is easier way.